# Powershell ConvertTo-HTML Shrinks Image in Table Cell

Tags: html, css, powershell

I'm using Powershell ConvertTo-HTML to build a three column table. I want to display a header image in the first row that spans all three columns. The table looks great but the image in the first row is like 1px thick.

I've tried resizing the columns, the image,  only using 1 column instead of spanning...

Here's the generate code from the Powershell script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <style>
                table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 700px;
                }

                td, th {
                    border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    font-family: Arial;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    padding: 8px;
                }

                th {
                    padding-top: 12px;
                    padding-bottom: 12px;
                    text-align: left;
                    background-color: #4286f4;
                    color: white;
                }
            </style>
</head><body>
<table>

         <tr>
            <td colspan='3' >
                <img src='file:///\\fileserver\files\file1.jpg'/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style='width:10%'></td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td style='width:10%'></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<table>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Jeff

Comment: something to do with the CSS, remove the CSS and check the image size to confirm.

Comment: To get hep with your code, **show* your code in a [mcve].

Comment: There's no style for `img`. I think you at least need `img { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The image was around 2,500px and way to large so was getting compressed into the space.

Thanks everyone for you suggestions.